# Export error after archive

Tags: ios, xcode

Getting the error mentioned in the image below when I click `Export --> Ad Hoc --> Next` after archiving my  application.
I am using xcode 9.0

**malformed JSON from ipatool: the 'supportedDeviceSets' key must be present and its value must be an array of dictionaries**

[image]

Comment: check "Show Logs" you can find more...